# How to create UDF in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator, udf

I have this code of UDF that stars with `create function...`

But I have NO idea where to put it inside the iseries navigator screen. can anyone help me? Google isn't helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the **Databases** branch to show all the DBs on the system..

Then either

- Right click on the DB and select **Run SQL Scripts**

or

- Expand the DB to show schemas
- Right click your selected schema and select **New-->Function-->SQL**

The first is probably your best option as you seem to have the complete source.

Comment: I'm using a black and green screen. Not really sure where the menus are. I've been playing with it. But worry not I've found the answer. Upvote for effort

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito If you are authorized to create SQL functions, you really should be using iNavigator for database work rather than a green-screen. You can copy/paste sections of text into a a green-screen a few lines at a time, but it gets very tricky once your function has more than maybe 16 lines or so or when any line has more than 75 characters or so. If you're just starting with DB2 SQL on i, green-screen has too many restrictions that take some experience and learning to get past.

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito...your OP said "iseries navigator screen"  which would imply the IBM iSeries Navigator component of IBM iSeries Access for Windows. Pic here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1014814&aid=1 (Note those are the old names, circa v5r4 or before)  "green and black screen" implies a simple 5250 session.  So which is it?

Comment: @Charles  It's literally a black/green screen, the text are green the background black. And yeah it's true, copy pasting sections of a text few lines at a time is very tricky, i'm not aware if it ad a iNavigator for database work though

Answer (score 1):

Enter it in the STRSQL window as a whole .. for example (the INSTRB UDF below)

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSTRB (C1 VarChar(4000), C2 VarChar(4000), N integer, M integer)
 RETURNS Integer
 SPECIFIC INSTRBOracleBase
 LANGUAGE SQL
 CONTAINS SQL
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE Pos, R, C2L Integer;

SET C2L = LENGTH(C2);

IF N > 0 THEN
   SET (Pos, R) = (N, 0);
   WHILE R < M AND Pos > 0 DO
      SET Pos = LOCATE(C2,C1,Pos);
         IF Pos > 0 THEN
         SET (Pos, R) = (Pos + 1, R + 1);
      END IF;
   END WHILE;

   RETURN (Pos - 1)*(1-SIGN(M-R));
ELSE
   SET (Pos, R) = (LENGTH(C1)+N, 0);
   WHILE R < M AND Pos > 0 DO
      IF SUBSTR(C1,Pos,C2L) = C2 THEN
         SET R = R + 1;
      END IF;
      SET Pos = Pos - 1;
   END WHILE;

   RETURN (Pos + 1)*(1-SIGN(M-R));
END IF;

END!
```

It should output  `Function INSTRB was created in QGPL.`

It is reusable